# How to log errors from the Telegram bot console

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

From time to time, errors appear in the telegram bot, and I would like to log them. In all "try:except" I set logging, but for some reason these errors pop up in the console and I cannot find a place to grab them

*I need to find not the cause of the problem, but how to log it from the console*

```
(__init__.py:445 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message can\'t be edited"}']"
```

[image]

---

At the end of the file I have such a construction, but for some reason it does not capture the error that I indicated above

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=1, timeout=20)
    except Exception as E:
        log(E)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[python-telegram-bot](/questions/tagged/python-telegram-bot) has his own [**Exception Handling**](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Exception-Handling);

Example;

```py
from telegram.error import (TelegramError, Unauthorized, BadRequest, 
                            TimedOut, ChatMigrated, NetworkError)

def error_callback(update, context):
    try:
        raise context.error
    except Unauthorized:
        # remove update.message.chat_id from conversation list
    except BadRequest:
        # handle malformed requests - read more below!
    except TimedOut:
        # handle slow connection problems
    except NetworkError:
        # handle other connection problems
    except ChatMigrated as e:
        # the chat_id of a group has changed, use e.new_chat_id instead
    except TelegramError:
        # handle all other telegram related errors

dispatcher.add_error_handler(error_callback)
```

---

Any other errors will be caught and logged by the Dispatcher. (As described in on there git page).

Small example of configuring the dispatcher;

```py
logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Could you clarify where can i find the `telegram.error` in the `telebot` aka `pyTelegramBotAPI`? when I enter `telebot.error` I cannot find this section

Comment: You can find it as part of the [telegram.error module](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.error.html)